# Calling a webservice from wsdl in java code

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am new in working with web services.I have got this `WSDL` file `URL`

```
**http://localhost:7101/MyWebServices-Webservices-context-root/ThePort?WSDL**
```

I know there are tools to call method from this web service just like `HTTP ANALYZER`.
I want to user above url to call method from the web service from java code. can i do that? if yes can someone please guide me how to?? 
Thanks. . . .

This is what i am trying

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7101/MyWebServices-Webservices-context-root/ThePort?WSDL");
            QName qname = new QName("http://example.com/", "HelloWorldService");
            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're going down this path? It's a lot of work: you'll have to build the SOAP envelope yourself, feed it to the service and process the SOAP response yourself also. Why?

Comment: I need make an application for which i want to call some methods from the web service.

Comment: Well, of course you want to call methods from the web service, why else would you be asking a web service-related question. *Why are you choosing this approach?* You could just use wsimport to generate the stubs for the service and be done, rather than trying to build your own message manually

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Eclipse IDE, the JavaEE perspective provides a suitable environment for developing web services and their clients.

Right-click the Project Explorer > New > Other > Web Service Client.

The Web Service Client window should appear. In the 'Service Definition' box, paste the WSDL file. If the file is valid, you should be able to create a client application where you will be able to call and execute the appropriate methods.